# Disable/remove javascript

Tags: theming, javascript, hooks

does anyone know how to disable a javascript loaded by drupal?

```
<script src="/profiles/ncr/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?ny8c02"></script>
```

I tried the following in the **template.php** file but no luck.

```
function bootstrap_ncr_js_alter(&$javascript) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'js_theme');
    unset($js[$path . '/bootstrap.js']);
}
```

Comment: Is that verbatim, because your parameter is passed in as `$javascript`, but you use `$js` in the `unset()`?

Comment: edit your theme's `.info` file, if js file is listed there, all you have to do is erase the line. Then clear the cache.

Comment: To add to what @MPD said, you are getting the path for the js_theme module, but the file is clearly /profiles/ncr/themes/contrib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js. Clearly, you are not referring to the same file.

Comment: @MPD my code would be `$path = drupal_get_path('module', '/profiles/ncr/themes/contrib/bootstrap');
 unset($javascript[$path . '/js/bootstrap.js']);`

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the JavaScript file you are trying to remove is actually coming from a theme. You were also trying to unset array item in non existing variable $js. You could try if this works for you:

```
function bootstrap_ncr_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap');
  unset($javascript[$path . '/js/bootstrap.js']);
}
```